# Google search with OS X spotlight

Tags: macos, google-search, spotlight

How can I use Spotlight to show Google search results?

The [Google Importer](http://www.caffeinatedcocoa.com/googleImporter/) is severely out of date, and does not work with 10.6.

And, if perhaps this isn't possible, I'd like to know the fastest and easiest way to execute a Google search from OS X.

Answer (score 2):

A possible alternative would be to use a program such as [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html) or [Google's Quick Search Box](http://www.google.com/quicksearchbox/) (made by the developer of Quicksilver).

Both options allow you to press a keyboard shortcut and quick launch applications, or perform a search.

For example; LaunchBar you would press your keyboard shortcut (eg. <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>) to bring LaunchBar to the front, then type an abbreviation for Google Search (eg. <kbd>g</kbd> or even <kbd>ggl</kbd> - it learns as you use it), press space and you can enter your search term. A Spotlight search would be done using a different abbreviation but the results of both searches would not be together.

Google Quick Search Box works similar but doesn't require you to explicitly state what kind of search you want to do (Spotlight or Google). It's also free compared to LaunchBar being shareware. You also need to [enable Spotlight results](http://www.google.com/support/quicksearchbox/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151105) in GQSB in order to view Spotlight results but like LaunchBar you can not view the Google Search results at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You might check out [Google Quick Search Box](http://code.google.com/p/qsb-mac/).  From their description:

> Quick Search Box is an open source
>   search box that allows you to search
>   data on your computer and across the
>   web. With Quick Search Box you can
>   search for information from just about
>   anywhere. You can then perform actions
>   on the search results, such as
>   launching applications, emailing
>   friends, or playing a song.

Comment: 5 minutes in, and this seems like a great little tool. Thank you. Does this project have roots in the Quicksilver app?

Comment: @landon9720 - The lead developer on GQSB is the original developer of Quicksilver

Comment: Glad to hear it!